# Desire2Learn - Final grade values in the UI different than the values obtained from the JSON response

Tags: desire2learn

The UI shows the following final grades for Student A:

```
17.15/42                  **Scheme: F**
```

But the JSON response (https://******/d2l/api/le/1.0/courseID/grades/final/values/studentIdentifier?x_a=*****&x_b=*******&x_c=********8&x_d=********&x_t=********) that I get is as follows:
{

PointsNumerator: 17.15,
PointsDenominator: 42,
WeightedNumerator: 17.15,
WeightedDenominator: 42,
GradeObjectIdentifier: "*******",
GradeObjectName: "Final Calculated Grade",
GradeObjectType: 7,
GradeObjectTypeName: null,
**DisplayedGrade: "B"**
}

The DisplayedGrade is F in D2L system but the JSON response shows that the DisplayedGrade is B. This happens to all the students in the course. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please let us know what version of the LMS you are making calls against: 9.4.1, 10.0.0?

Comment: Priyanka: it's quite possible that you've run into a defect that's been identified and addressed. Can you please check out your support options (http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/about.html#support) and then follow up by either opening an issue in the tracker, or contacting the Valence dev team directly?

Comment: Viktor: Yes an issue has been opened with the Valence dev team. Will let you know when I receive an response. Will let you know in a bit about the version of the LMS.

Comment: Viktor: The learning environment is 9.4.1 SP4

Comment: Priyanka -- ah! yes; that's instructive. I will coordinate to followup with your report to the Valence dev team.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your LMS has a known issue: if a grade schema is created with entries "out of order", then grades fetched through the API can have the schema symbols associated differently with grade values than you would find through the main web UI. To workaround this issue, create grade schemas in one go, with items starting from a score of 0 going up in order to the maximum value.